# Token Authentication Not Working on Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I have a Django application, which I am using DRF for my API with Session, and Token authentication. I have rest_framework, and rest_framework.authtoken in my installed apps. I have migrated my database and can create tokens for users in the Django Admin. I know all of this is working because I am accessing rest_framework.auth_token's obtain_auth_token view for returning a token when user data is submitted in a POST request, and receive one back. When I try to make a GET request to a view function in my app that has TokenAuthentication on its viewset, it keeps returning.

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

**Settings File**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # My Apps
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
}
```

**URLS**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.authtoken import views

from api.views.some_model import MyViewSet

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('rest-auth/', include('rest_auth.urls')),
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

**Viewset**

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication, TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from some_app.models import SomeModel
from api.serializers.exams import SomeModelSerializer


class ExamViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication, SessionAuthentication)

    queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SomeModelSerializer
```

**Python Script to Get Response**

```
import requests
import json

data = {
    "username": "myemail@gmail.com",
    "password": "password124"
}
url = "http://localhost:8002/api/v1/api-token-auth/"
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
token = json.loads(response.text).get('token')

if token:
    token = f"Token {token}"
    headers = {"Authentication": token}
    response = requests.get("http://localhost:8002/api/v1/model/", headers=headers)
    print(response.text)
else:
    print('No Key')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Header name should be `Authorization` not `Authentication`:

```
headers = {"Authorization": token}
response = requests.get("http://localhost:8002/api/v1/model/", headers=headers)
```

Comment: Womp Womp. rookie mistake, how embarrassing hah. Thank you very much neverwalkaloner.

Comment: I just fell into the same trap. It is so easy to make this mistake if you have spent hours developing "authentication"-enabled views.

Answer (score 0):

The token should be provided in the header like

```
 -H  "Authorization: Token 8fa36c01df3bb9ed31fc2329c53a9fe2cac72966"
```

Answer (score -2):

Authorization: **Bearer** < your-token-here >
and if you are using Django Rest Framework the default prefix is **JWT**.

Comment: Authorization: JWT your-token-here
Their is no such syntax like that, this is valid Authorization: Bearer your-token-here